# Cannot add Foreign Key MySQL :errno 150

Tags: mysql, sql

I try add foreign key:

```
   CREATE TABLE `invoices` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ` name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `code_text` text NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;




  CREATE TABLE `leads` (
  `lead_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   ...
   PRIMARY KEY (`lead_id`)
  );



CREATE TABLE `leads_invoices` (
leads_invoice_id int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
   invoice_id int(11) NOT NULL,
   lead_id_i  int(11) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY(leads_invoice_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (invoice_id) REFERENCES invoices(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (lead_id_i) REFERENCES leads(lead_id)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

But I got error with my  lead_id_i key:

> Can't create table `crm_test`.`leads_invoices` (errno: 150 "Foreign
>   key constraint is incorrectly formed")

I checked all types and tables, seems they are correct..
How can I solve this problem? Hope you will help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You have to add `ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8` to leads table

```
CREATE TABLE `leads` (
  `lead_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   ...
   PRIMARY KEY (`lead_id`)
  )ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Because if you want to add a foreign key, both tables must have the same engine

Comment: Thanks, it saved me